# startAfter() in RealTime Database Firebase

Tags: c#, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How do you get a snapshot with a start point, but exclude the first item?

For example

```
 task5 = await FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.GetReference("Students").OrderByKey().startAt("Bob").GetValueAsync().ContinueWith(t => t);
```

The result gives me-  "Bob" key + the next items. But I don't want to have Bob in the snapshot but 1 after that.

I know that FireStore has a function called  startAfter() which is perfect, but I don't see it with realtime DB,  what's the way to do it and not include it in the snapshot itselff?

Comment: Hey SHAI. Did you see my answer? Do you have any additional questions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `startAfter` operation (nor an `endBefore`) in the Firebase Realtime Database API. You'll have to read the extra item, and then discard it in your C# code.

It is a reasonable request by the way, so I'd recommend [filing a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/). But for now, you'll have to read and discard the extra node.

Comment: Thank you. I'll accept the answer even though it's not a real solution but that's not our fault there's no such feature. I did fill a feature request, hopefully they'll work on it, it sounds pretty simple to add it for them.

Comment: SHAI, I did fill another feature request about "startAfter" in RTDB too ("startAt" generates too much unnecessary traffic), but if they have not performed your request for a whole year, then there is no hope 